# Lumia 820 / Black update / Glance

Tags: apps, lumia-black-update, glance

Recently I have my Lumia 820 updated to Black, unfortunately Glance is nowhere to be found in settings; I've tried restarting and rebooting the phone but to no avail; I've also purchased and installed the app with the 'gear' icon which is meant to be 'display' - however it still doesn't appear anywhere.
I'd be grateful if sb could help to solve the problem. Thanks ;)